VSCode quick fix does not suggest imports from a Python package in the same workspace
 Overview 
I have a VSCode workspace which contains two directories. In one is my main application, in another is a common package used by this application and a couple of others.
  # main-app.code-workspace
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "."
    },
    {
      "path": "../common/shared_package"
    }
  ],

I am able to import classes from the shared package if I manually type out the import string (from shared_package.utils.clock import SuperClock), but VSCode's quick-fix isn't offering any help with this.


Imports from other dependencies typically work with quick-fix (eg if I type trio I get an Auto-Import suggestion from VS Code)
Imports from within main-app also work fine with quick-fix
Manually typing out the import to pull in classes from shared_package is fine
Quick fix does not work with shared_package classes

 Additional Info 

This is a Python project which uses Poetry for dependency management
my pyproject.toml file includes this line

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
shared-hub-be = { path = "../common/shared_package", develop = true }


I think it might be a red herring, but I am seeing this error (and only this error) in output when I open VSCode

2024-08-01 10:50:48.793 [error] Error: spawn pixi ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn pixi',
  path: 'pixi',
  spawnargs: [ '--version' ]
}


"python.languageServer": "Pylance" is set in workspace file

 What have I tried so far 
I did what any of us would do and spent 6 months manually typing out the import statements.
Beyond that I tried some back and forth with ChatGPT - it suggested

Add the following to both my VSCode settings file and the Workspace settings file.

"python.analysis.extraPaths": ["../common/shared_package"]


Update PYTHONPATH to include /absolute/path/to/common/shared_package
Try removing develop=true and then rerunning poetry install

None of this stuff helped and has now been reverted.

Hello, under the same workspace, you can try using the relative import module. I was very happy to see you say that the problem has now been restored. If you can, you can edit the answer to the workaround and post it. I think this is helpful for other members who are having similar issues, thank you very much.

Hey Jeanneli
Sorry, to be clear this issue has not been resolved. What do you mean by using the relative import module?

if shared_package can be installed by pip, and you have a virtual environment, you can install it in editable mode with pip -e.

Sorry, the relative import is based on the location of the current module. Use something like from .import shared_package.utils.clock. Does using relative import like this solve the problem? You need to make sure that the environment of the interpreter you are currently selecting has shared_package installed.

@Jeanneli, again just clarifying that I can import from shared_package with from shared_package.utils.clock import SuperClock. Manually typing it is fine and always has been. My problem is that quick fix is seemingly not aware of the package and so does not suggest importing from it when a class isn't found.
@darda, I'm using poetry which installs packages as editable when develop = true is set in pyproject.toml as it is here.
See: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/34#issuecomment-1193365526

Sorry, I misunderstood. This could be a bug. Do you use code --disable-extensions to start the check, what message is prompted? What version of vscode are you using?
